# ASP.Net Webservice receiving an undefined number of key-value pairs

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I've been working with some form processing providers and they seem to have a generic receiver for key-value pair data. I'm attempting to do this but every data-structure i've tried to use implements an interface and therefore cannot serialize the container for use in the webmethod.

I've even tried using the base 'object' data type - with no success

```
[WebMethod] 
        public void processResponse( object lead ){
            Dictionary<string, string> DList = (Dictionary<string,string>) lead;
```

How can I receive an undefined number of key-value pairs using this webservice so i can perform business logic on the received data and intelligently route the data using a unified input method? Statically typed classes will not work in this instance as different types of leads have different numbers of fields/properties.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using legacy ASMX services instead of WCF?

Comment: So, you mean there's no reason not to use WCF? Then my suggestion is to use WCF.

Comment: I know nothing about WCF - and stopping progress to learn a new side isnt real savvy practice. Perhaps in the future this will be an option

Comment: It's because WCF uses DataContractSerializer which can serialize key value pairs. If you put `Dictionary<T,K>` as your parameter, it won't work with *.asmx but WILL work with WCF service.

Comment: Wasn't being snide at all. The answer to almost any limitation in ASMX is "use WCF". The answer to "I don't have time to learn WCF" is "it doesn't take a significant amount of time to learn the subset of WCF that's equivalent to what you're doing with ASMX".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was add a generic handler. I copied the QueryString parameter into a Dictionary and worked with the values from there. It sets a central point of data-collection and I was able to apply my business logic from there -- seems to have suited the purpose of what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to WCF, which by default uses the `DataContractSerializer` class capable of serializing key-value pairs like the `Dictionary<T,K>`.

The basic structure of your service will be exactly the same and using BasicHttpBinding you have almost the same communication protocol based on Http and Soap. Spend 30 minutes on a WCF tutorial and you'll barely want to go back to old *.asmxes.